# WordPress callback function is called twice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

i have been developing a WordPress plugin that has a form that sends some data to a Database.
My problem is that every time i click the submit button the callback runs twice, and the information that appears in my database is duplicated.

My jQuery code is:

```
 $("#submit_btn").click( function (event) {
            
            event.preventDefault();
            let uuid = uuidv4()



            let form_serialize = $("form").serializeArray();

            let dataForm = {
                "id": uuid, 
                'submitId': uuid 
            }

            $.each(form_serialize, function (i, field) {
                dataForm[field.name] = field.value
            });

            $.ajax({
                    url: ccandidates.ajax_url,
                    type: "POST",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    cache: false,
                    data: {
                        security: candidates.ajax_nonce,
                        action: 'SendToFormApi',
                        data: dataForm
                    },

                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data, status, xhttp) {
                        // event.preventDefault();
                        if (data === true) {
                            window.location = candidates.merci_page_url;
                        } else {
                            window.location.href = candidates.error_page_url;

                            $("form").trigger('reset')
                        }
                    },
                }
            );

        });
```

Callback function

```
function SendToFormApi_callback()
{
    $formRandyValues = $_POST['data'];
    $virtualagencyApiEmail = new virtualagencyApiEmail();
    $result = $virtualagencyApiEmail->NyFormApi($formRandyValues);
    $response = $virtualagencyApiEmail->NyFormApiCall($result,$formMyValues['id']);

    $code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response);
    // if code 503 == service unavailable
    // if code 401 == auth fail
    // if code 400 == object fail
    // if code 201 == success response

    if ($code === 201) {
        echo json_encode(true);
        wp_die();
    } else {
        echo json_encode(false);
        wp_die();
    }

}

add_action('wp_ajax_SendToFormApi', 'SendToFormApi_callback', 1);
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_SendToFormApi', 'SendToFormApi_callback', 1);
```

```
    public function NyFormApi($params): array
    {

        $uuidId = $params['id'] ?? $this->getUid();

        $position_criteria_object = new Position_Criteria();
        $position_criteria_object->type = 'string';
        $position_criteria_object->label = 'besoin';
        $position_criteria_object->question = 'votre_besoin';
        $position_criteria_object->answer = $params['votreBesoin'];
        $position_criteria_object->value = $params['votreBesoin'];

        $origin_object = new Position_Criteria();
        $origin_object->type = 'string';
        $origin_object->label = 'origin';
        $origin_object->question = 'candidature_oringin';
        $origin_object->answer = 'My form';
        $origin_object->value = 'My form';

        $secteur_object = new Position_Criteria();
        $secteur_object->type = 'string';
        $secteur_object->label = 'secteur';
        $secteur_object->question = 'secteur';
        $secteur_object->answer = $params['secteur'];
        $secteur_object->value = $params['secteur'];

        $region_object = new Position_Criteria();
        $region_object->type = 'string';
        $region_object->label = 'region';
        $region_object->question = 'region';
        $region_object->answer = $params['region'];
        $region_object->value = $params['region'];

        $metier_object = new Position_Criteria();
        $metier_object->type = 'string';
        $metier_object->label = 'metier';
        $metier_object->question = 'metier';
        $metier_object->answer = $params['metier'];
        $metier_object->value = $params['metier'];


        $talent_object = new Talent();
        $talent_object->id = $uuidId; 
        $talent_object->firstName = $params['firstName'];
        $talent_object->lastName = $params['lastName'];
        $talent_object->email = $params['email'];
        $talent_object->phone = $params['phone'];

        if(empty($params['qualificationCode'])){
            $qualificationCode = "none";
        } else {
            $qualificationCode = $params['qualificationCode'];
        }



        return array(
            'headers' => array(
                'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode($this->keyEncoded)
            ),
            'body' => array(
                'id' => $uuidId, //$params['id'], // str
                'workTeamId' => $params['postClient'], // str
                'priority' => 1, // int
                'positionCriteria' => array(
                    $position_criteria_object,
                    $origin_object,
                    $secteur_object,
                    $region_object,
                    $metier_object
                ),  // [{...},{...},...]
                'occupationCode' => $qualificationCode, // str,
                'occupationLabel' => $params['qualification'], // str
                'talent' => $talent_object, // { key = value, ... }
            )
        );
    }

    public function MyFormApiCall($params, $id)
    {
        $url = $this->apiPathRandy . "/" . $id;
        return wp_remote_post($url, $params);
    }


    // Get an RFC-4122 compliant globaly unique identifier
    private function getUid(): string
    {
        $data = PHP_MAJOR_VERSION < 7 ? openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16) : random_bytes(16);
        $data[6] = chr(ord($data[6]) & 0x0f | 0x40);    // Set version to 0100
        $data[8] = chr(ord($data[8]) & 0x3f | 0x80);    // Set bits 6-7 to 10
        return vsprintf('%s%s-%s-%s-%s-%s%s%s', str_split(bin2hex($data), 4));
    }
```

After reading and trying some solutions that i found, no of them work in my case.

Thank you for your help.

(note: there are some vars names that were changed for privacy)

Comment: Start by checking what happens on the client side (dev tools, network panel) - is this causing just one POST request, or two?

Comment: @CBroe it s making two post calls. I ve checked the dev tools in the browser.

Comment: WHY use Ajax when you redirect the page anyway? Just redirect from whatever is in ccandidates.ajax_url or a super simple server page and submit a form without any scripting at all

Comment: Any JavaScript errors? (Set your console to keep the content when the page changes, so that you don't miss any.) Other than that, I can't see a reason here, why this should cause two requests - unless maybe the `$("#submit_btn").click(...)` itself executed more than once, so that the submit button would have multiple click handlers now?

Comment: @CBroe thank you, it seems my ```$("#submit_btn").click(...)``` is being called twice... still have to understand how to prevent this

Comment: Perhaps the event handler assignment is inside something that is called twice...

Comment: @CBroe after digging some more i added unbind("click") before the .click and it seems to work. In my digging in the code i found that we are injecting 3 different versions of jQuery in our site :( . Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: @mplungjan thank you for your suggestion, that what we think. But it wanst me who develop the site, so i feel a little lost right now...have to continue looking at the code to discover all things. cheers

Comment: @mplungjan yes you are right, my event handler is being called twice... i found out that i have different jQuery versions and i believe that i m having problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove all javascript from the form and do

```
if ($code === 201) {
    header("location: merci.html");
    wp_die();
} else {
    header("location: erreur.html");
    wp_die();
}
```